# Measuring temperature while benchmarking on Linux

Tags: linux, benchmarking, temperature

I want to measure the temperature and frequency of a two socket machine while performing the High-Performance Linpack benchmark.

I wrote a shell script `sensor.sh` that I start in the background with `sh sensors.sh &`  and then proceed to the benchmark.

```
for ((;;))
do
awk 'BEGIN{ORS=" ";} $2=="MHz" {print $4} END {print "\n"}' /proc/cpuinfo >> cpuf.dat

awk 'BEGIN{ORS=" ";} {print $1} END {print "\n"}' /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.?/hwmon/hwmon?/temp*_input >> cput.dat
 sleep .1
done
```

I get my outputfiles, however the timestamps are not 0.1s apart from each other. I guess the system is busy and the shell script process is not executed that often. HPL says it has a runtime of ~1100s, in this time my temperature.dat file generated ~4600 entries.

Is there another way I can measure the temperature and frequency while performing my benchmark program and store the output in a `.dat` file?

Comment: A performance benchmark will necessarily make the machine busy, so everything else will be competing for the system resources with the benchmark. And your temperature monitoring code will also slow down the benchmark, impacting its results. You need to somehow monitor the temperature using something external to the machine you're running the benchmark on.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can gain external access to the machine as it's in my university's cluster. I'll look into if they have monitor modules installed. In this measurement I try to see the warm-up period from job launch to the time it settles for a temperature and frequency, so a small slow down is fine (it seems to be ~1%). Do you know any other approaches I could try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is very inefficient, requiring a lot of separate processes to each get some CPU time before it can run the next `sleep  .1` so yes, system load is going to make it run less frequently.

Also, `sensors` is relatively expensive; maybe use command line options to have it only check CPU temp.  Or I think CPU temp is available from files in `/proc` or `/sys` directly.

---

`xargs` with no arguments defaults to `echo`, so it's just an inefficient way to collapse whitespace characters (including newline) to spaces.  (If you use `printf '%s\n' foo bar | strace -f xargs` you can see it actually does fork + execve `/bin/echo` instead of simply printing the output itself like you could do with `sed` or `tr`.)

you could use more efficient commands for text processing that need less CPU time, and fewer context switches by piping through fewer separate processes.  e.g. `sensors` piped into just one `awk` command that does all the text processing.  And `sed -n 's/cpu MHz : //p' /proc/cpuinfo >> frequency.dat` to avoid a useless use of cat (and xargs).

But that's still going to have some overhead.

---

**You could write one `perl` script that pipes from `sensors`, and closes/reopens `/proc/cpuinfo`.**  That would avoid all the system calls that process startup makes.

**Instead of sleeping for a fixed time, you can have it check the current time and sleep until the next multiple of `0.1` seconds.**  You could do that with bash, too, but that will require running even more commands and you want to cause as few context switches as possible for your benchmark.

---

You could also or instead label each line with current time, so you know when each sample came from.  To do this without needing to start another external process, use bash's `$EPOCHREALTIME`.  Like `{ echo -n "$EPOCHREALTIME  "; awk ...; } >> cpuf.dat` if you're still using bash instead of Perl.

Comment: I use `xargs` to gain a single line of output instead of 48 for each core, so my .dat file has the structure that each row is a point in time and each column is a core temperature or frequency. I avoided pipelines now (but the last) see edit and will try again. I'm not familiar with pearl yet but open to try it out.

Comment: @Luke: Oh, to convert newline into space?  You can do that as part of one invocation of `sed` that's also filtering something else, or with `tr` to delete newlines along with other things.  `xargs` with no args defaults to `echo` as the command, so it actually forks + execs `/bin/echo`, running yet another process.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks. I managed to squeeze both calls into a single `awk`. I'm going to test if the results get better. But as far as I understood it is not possible to measure the cpu stats without overhead? Would a pearl script consume less resources?

Comment: @Luke: yes, writing the loop in Perl script (spelling: not pearl) would use less CPU time, and make fewer system calls.  Starting up a process makes a lot of system calls; use `strace` to see; starting awk twice per 0.1 second is not much but still something.  Writing the loop in Perl means you can do more without making extra system calls, like calculating how long to sleep until the next multiple of `0.1` seconds.  (clock_gettime runs purely in user-space thanks to the VDSO).  To do that in bash, you'd need to run `date` or do some processing on `$EPOCHREALTIME`

Answer (score 2):

You could try running your code with high priority, so it will be less impacted by the load of the benchmark. But you need to run as root to be able to use negative niceness.

```
nice -n -10 bash
for ((;;))
do
 sensors | grep Core | awk '{print $3}' | tr '+' ' '  | tr '°C' ' ' | xargs >> temperature.dat
 cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "cpu MHz" | tr "cpu MHz : " " " | xargs >> frequency.dat
 sleep .1
done
exit
```

Comment: Sadly I do not have root access to the machine, but I tried to make the script more efficient